# How to extend existing macro with \edef?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

`\edef` does expansion, but does not execute the commands. How in the following example make so that `\foo` will do assignment to `\tmp` at the moment of its call, not when it is defined? Why `\foo` produces `0F` instead of `1F`? Using `\let` in `\bar` works as needed. Also, calling `\baz` gives `TeX capacity exceeded`. Why?

```
\def\foo{F}
\def\bar{B}
\def\baz{Z}
\newcount\tmp
\newcount\N

\edef\foo{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp \foo}
\N=1
\foo

\let\oldbar = \bar
\def\bar{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp \oldbar}
\N=2
\bar

\expandafter\def\expandafter\baz\expandafter{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp \baz}
\N=3
%\baz

\bye
```

Comment: Why use `\edef` if you don't want expansion exactly?

Comment: @cfr: The variant with `\let` is not very clean. I'm curious if there is a way to do this without intermediate assignments.

Comment: `\edef\foo{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \noexpand\the\tmp \foo}
\N=1\foo`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes What if before `\the\tmp` we need to do `\advance\tmp by 1`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the `\if aa \N \fi` immediately expands in the `\edef` to `<spacetoken>\N`, thus we find at the start of the replacement text of `\foo` the assignment `\tmp=<spacetoken><spacetoken>\N`. **No** assignment is executed at the time of an `\edef`  definition. The two spaces will be gobbled as they are a `<filler>`, at the time the `\foo` macro is expanded and the assignment is finally done.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  The count `\tmp` will then acquire the value stored in the count `\N` at the time `\foo` will be expanded. The `\the\tmp` in  `\foo` on the other hand expands immediately to the value stored in `\tmp` at the time of `\foo` edef-definition. Idem for the `\foo` at the end of its own replacement text.

Comment: in the `\baz` example the `\expandafter`'s do nothing, because `\tmp` is a count, hence an unexpandable token. Thus we have `\def\baz{stuff...\baz}`. This definition can be done but when `\baz` is expanded naturally we end up in a never-finishing recursive loop, hence the `TeX capacity exceeded`.

Comment: @jbfu Thanks for bringing sanity to my madness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that the definition of `\foo` is augmented by something at the beginning of the replacement text, the method is very standard:

```
\def\leftadd#1#2{% #1 is a parameterless macro, #2 a token list
  \toks0=\expandafter{#1}% store the expansion of #1
  \toks2={#2}% store the token list
  \edef#1{\the\toks2 \the\toks0}% redefine #1
}
```

Several other methods have been proposed, this is possibly the easiest to understand. It's based on the rule that tokens delivered by `\the<toks register>` are not expanded any more in an `\edef`.

With e-TeX extensions one can dispense with the token registers:

```
\def\leftadd#1#2{\edef#1{\unexpanded{#2}\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}
```

Now

```
\def\foo{F}
\leftadd\foo{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp}
```

is equivalent to having defined `\foo` by

```
\def\foo{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp F}
```

in the first place.

---

A token register free version:

```
\def\leftadd#1#2{\expandafter\leftaddaux\expandafter{#1}{#2}{#1}}
\def\leftaddaux#1#2#3{\def#3{#2#1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Upon EDIT, this addresses all the issues raised by the OP, regarding `\foo` and `\baz`.  It also addresses subsequent issues raised by the OP in comments.

The `\foo` fix works by placing a `\noexpand` prior the `\the\tmp` in the `\foo` definition.  And, in response to the OP's comment, it has no problem if `\tmp` must be advanced, as shown in the MWE.

The `\baz` fix involves expanding all the way out to `\baz` before setting the result in the new `\baz` definition.  I placed a pile of stuff in `\glob` to simplify that process.  Also EDITED to demonstrate `\advance\tmp` as part of `\baz` solution.

RE-EDITED to address other cases the OP asks in comments:

`\painful` is like `\baz`, but without using `\glob`.

`\superbaz` demonstrates the use of before and after `\tmp` values all at once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo{F}
\def\bar{B}
\def\painful{W}
\def\baz{Z}
\newcount\tmp
\newcount\N

\edef\foo{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \advance\tmp by 7 \noexpand\the\tmp \foo}
\N=1
\foo

\let\oldbar = \bar
\def\bar{\tmp = \if aa \N \fi \the\tmp \oldbar}
\N=2
\bar

\def\glob{\tmp = \if aa \N  \fi \advance\tmp by 2\noexpand\the\tmp}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\baz\expandafter{\expandafter\glob\baz}
\N=3
\baz

\expandafter\def\expandafter\painful\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp%
  \expandafter\expandafter\if\expandafter a\expandafter a%
  \expandafter\N\expandafter\fi\expandafter\the\expandafter\tmp\painful}
\N=4
\painful

\verb+\tmp+ is currently \the\tmp
\edef\superbaz{\the\tmp Z}

\def\glob{\tmp = \if aa \N  \fi \advance\tmp by 2\noexpand\the\tmp}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\superbaz\expandafter{\expandafter\glob\superbaz}
\N=5
\superbaz

%\bye
\end{document}
```

[image]

FINAL ADDENDUM:

In answer to the OP comment `How to leave \the\tmp only in \superbaz and remove from \def\glob? (so that only 7Z will be printed). Also, how to do the same without \def\glob?`

Beating a dead horse...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\tmp
\newcount\N

\def\ultimatebaz{\the\tmp Z}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\ultimatebaz\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter\expandafter\if\expandafter a\expandafter a%
  \expandafter\N\expandafter\fi\expandafter\advance\expandafter\tmp%
  \expandafter b\expandafter y\expandafter 2\expandafter\noexpand\ultimatebaz}
\N=5
\ultimatebaz\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `\noexpand` do and why only `\the\tmp` is executed at the moment of definition? What if we put `\the\tmp` *inside* `\def\foo`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko  The `\noexpand` prevents `\the\tmp` from being expanded during the `\edef`.  Expanded, in this context, I am thinking, is equivalent to evaluation.

Comment: Is it possible to use `\edef` when `\the\tmp` is inside `\def\foo`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I think my `\baz` fix addresses this final question.  No?

Comment: Is it possible to do this not using `\def\glob`?

Comment: `\expandafter\def\expandafter\baz\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\expandafter\expandafter\if\expandafter a\expandafter a\expandafter\N\expandafter\fi\expandafter\the\expandafter\tmp\baz}
\N=3
\baz`, but why put one's self through such pain.  The grouping in a `\glob` is an oft used convenient trick.

Comment: This works. But where in this chain must be put `\advance\tmp by 1`? I do not fully understand how it works. Also, what if we need `\the\tmp` inside original `\def\baz` and not in new `\baz`? (i.e., `\def\baz{\the\tmp Z}` and no `\the\tmp` inside `\expandafter...`). There may be other people reading this, so please add to the main answer.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Please see comprehensive edit.

Comment: Your solution is good. But `\superbaz` currently produces `74Z`. How to leave `\the\tmp` only in `\superbaz` and remove from `\def\glob`? (so that only `7Z` will be printed). Also, how to do the same without `\def\glob`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Done.

Comment: Is it possible to trace how the expansion is done? How to understand what TeX does?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko `\tracingall` is your (sort of) friend: with e-TeX one can get a bit more info from this than in 'classical' TeX (even if you don't use the other extensions).